# Android Awareness of remote Bluetoth-Request with disabled BluetoothAdapter

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'd like to use android's bluetooth for some kind of sensing devices. But  I don't want to connect to these devices. As far as I know Devices won't react to scanning when their own bluetooth is disabled. But is there any way to get my app noticed when such a scan has been performed by a remote device, even when my app is running with bluetooth turned off?

I don't want to force toggling bluetooth on, but I need to get some kind of Action started in other devices running the same app. So I'm wondering if some there is any description/data field that can be sent with a bluetooth scan, so if scan is rejected the app has the opportunity to read that data just to know there was this specific call?

I need to leverage context-awareness within my system as to users, not knowing each other, still can interchange content (if they agree). But I need to find some ways of sensing while I also don't want to have all sensors activated all the time.

Hope you can give me a hint, or tell me that this is simply not possible, which would also help me not spending any more time on that.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your effort, what have you done so far? What resources or articles have you found and what problems did you experience when you tried to implement this feature.

Comment: Actually I don't have started implementing this so far. I just wanted to get a hint concerning the possibility of doing that. I'm a little used to android now, and I have read the documentation for bluetooth on developer.android.com, but can not read from there if the BluetoothAdapter just throws away all scans, if the device has Bluetooth disabled. If it is like that, I guess I don't have to start implementing such a feature. Otherwise I could like identify my app within a bluetooth scanning request and the app on other devices can then ask the user to maybe enable bluetooth for this app.

Comment: This is not meant as asking for code, sorry if it sounded like that at first.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no one will write code or do some researches for you, don't think that your time is more valuable that the time of other people. We are here to solve problems that people face with

Comment: As I said, exactly what you say is NOT what I wanted...I just was not sure if it is worth to follow this plan and wanted to ask id someone has had experience with something like that. As I said above I do not want code from others, and just wanted to know if this is possible. I guess it is hard to be clear sometimes. Thanks for your reply anyway.